# Find log filenames that MUST end with any char but not only ".log"

Tags: linux, find

I need to find all log files older than 5 days and that the filename MUST ends with .log AND any character (i.e. first.log20210701 but not first.log).
I tried this command  but it shows also ".log"

```
find . -type f -name '*.log*' -mtime +5
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Should `file.login123.log` or `something.logger.log` be found or not?  Could you please clarify the exact requirements for the filenames to search for?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this (`.+` means "one or more characters"):

```
find . -regex ".*\.log.+" -mtime +5
```

Or, POSIXly (the `?` requires any one character, thus `?*` means "one or more characters"):

```
find . -name "*.log?*" -mtime +5
```

Comment: This would still potentially find files that have names ending in `.log` _if_ the name contained `.log` elsewhere as well.

Comment: @Kusalananda, technically, such names end with "`.log` AND any character[s]", which is what they say they want there. But it's perhaps a bit unclear what they want in that corner case, so maybe you should ask that as a comment on the question?

Comment: @ilkkachu I've asked for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.log*' ! -name '*.log' -mtime +5
```

Simply disallow filenames ending in `.log`, this is what `! -name '*.log'` does.

This would find `first.log20210701`, but not `first.log` or `first.log20210701.log` or `first.login.log`.